# update the selected values manually in Angular-2 Multiselect dropdown

Tags: angular

I have used softsimon angular-2-multiselect-dropdown in a differen component which is loaded on a click under a nav Bar. Once the user selects the options in the dropdown , i'm extracting the selected option in a variable . Once the nav bar is closed and opened again , i want the selected options to be shown in the dropdown instead of creating the view once again . Is there a way ?

Dropdown Code :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.optionArray=this._filterComponent.getParameters();
    for(let x = 0; x < this.optionArray.length ; x++ ){
        this.optionArrayObject.push({id : x , name :    this.optionArray[x]});
    }
}
public onChange() : void {
    console.log(this.selectedTexts);
    this.selectedOptionsArray=[];
    this.selectedoptionsString='';
    for(let y = 0; y < this.selectedTexts.length; y++){
       for(let x = 0; x < this.optionArrayObject.length; x++){
           if(this.optionArrayObject[x].id == this.selectedTexts[y]){
             this.selectedOptionsArray.push(this.optionArrayObject[x].name);
           }
       }
    }
    if(this.selectedTexts.length == 0){
        this.selectedoptionsString = this.selectedOptionsArray.join(',');
    }
    else{
        this.selectedoptionsString = this.selectedOptionsArray.join(',');
    }
    this.optionsString.emit(this.selectedoptionsString);
}
```

html:

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="buidArrayObject" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [ngModel]="selectedTexts"></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

This is a different component which is used in menu component inside a side nav bar.

Is there a way the selected option is still shown even after it(nav bar) is closed and opened again?